# How to log IP address using logback?

Tags: logging, logback

Using logback, I'm trying to log IP address. I got to know about logging of `hostname` but I'm not able to log the local IP of the server.Is there any way I can print the local IP address of the server using logback.

Below is the pattern I'm using for hostname printing.

```
<appender name="APP_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/nifi-app.log</file>
        <define name="hostname" class="ch.qos.logback.core.property.CanonicalHostNamePropertyDefiner"/>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!--
              For daily rollover, use 'app_%d.log'.
              For hourly rollover, use 'app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
              To GZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.gz'.
              To ZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.zip'.
            -->
            <fileNamePattern>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/nifi-app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- keep 30 log files worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>${hostname}%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624814/in-nifi-how-to-log-ip-address-of-the-server not flagging as duplicate as it is unanswered

Comment: The linked question got deleted, I checked but there was no answer yet (also no deleted answer) so this question remains open.